# How Can I Change UIImages in a ScrollView based on a User's Input

Tags: objective-c, ipad, user-interface, uiscrollview

Okay gang, I'm scratching my head on how to accomplish this one so I wanted to put it out to the world at large.

Essentially what a client wants is a way to toggle PART of a view based on whether the user selects a "Yes" or "No" option.  My question is how would I go about accomplishing that?

Allow me to provide some more details.  Within this specific app resides a form (a form with custom text fields, picker views, switches, sliders and other UI elements) that have all been laid out in a Storyboard, then programmed to function.  About 3/4 of the way down this form, the user will be greeted with a "Yes" or "No" option and a button for each.  The trick is that each view needs to have its own UI elements (text fields, sliders and buttons) appear ONLY when one of the options is selected and only BELOW the "Yes" or "No" option (all the elements above it need to remain, stay in the same place and hold the information the user enters).

An example : If the user hits the "Yes" button, below it 3 lines of text followed by a UIButton and Text Field would appear.  Underneath this, other navigation buttons which navigate to other ViewControllers would appear.  However, if the user hits the "No" button , all of those items I mentioned a moment ago would need to disappear, and instead a different set of text fields, labels, buttons and background image would need to appear.  The navigation buttons will also need to link to other ViewControllers, different from the buttons in the "Yes" option.  At this point I suggested to the client that a Navigation controller rooted at the bottom of the screen would be a good idea, but they are vehemently opposed to this and instead want the navigation options to be "dynamic" (or change according to which option is pressed, "Yes" or "No").

I have thought to attempt this programatically by simply using each button to load in a different image, this works just fine.  The hitch then becomes twofold;
1) When I attempt to load the other UI elements that I get no way to lay them out in a storyboard and thus they appear in sporadic locations and 
2) All this needs to be contained within a scroll view, which ALSO needs to change its size depending on how much space is needed below the yes and no option.  Naturally the "Yes" section is 3 times smaller than the "No" section.

So, any ideas on how to make all this happen?  I should mention at this point that the client also does not wish to simply navigate to a different ViewController, they very much want all this to occur on the same screen.  I wish I had some code to share but we are still in the "design" aspect of this project and as such, very little code has been written.  Any advice will be much appreciated as I've never been greeted with this type of build request before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UINavigationController object and set your view(say yourViewController) where your Yes and No buttons exist as a root view controller as below

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
```

Now when user press YES/NO button on yourViewController view than you can programmatically create all controls text field and buttons and set frame according to your view. like

```
UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(enter frame accordinglly)];
[self.view addSubview:txtField];
```

same you can add more controls like buttons or any other controls.

after that when user press any the button(on which you want another view to display) you can push other view in the navController as below

```
[navController pushViewController:otherViewController animated:YES];
```

you need to keep track of navController in your yourViewController

when you want to go back just pop view from  navController

```
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

PS: please be watchful for memory deallocation as well.

Comment: Thanks for this solution suraj, I'll give it a go later today and post back my results.

Comment: Thanks again suraj, this wasn't exactly the solution I was looking for in this particular instance (I only wanted to change a section of the ViewController's content, not the entire ViewController) but this solution worked just fine upon testing.  Appreciate it!

Comment: thanks @Slider257, I'm really happy that my answer is helped you in any of the manner in your problem.

Comment: I've encountered a slight hiccup here and was wondering you have any useful pointers.

I have created some buttons programatically, and they "appear" in the view fine.  However, when I click on them they do not give a push down animation as other buttons do in Simulator.  

I also need these buttons to perform segues.  I have setup the segues with custom identifiers, however the only way I've seen this work is to give an IBAction to the button.  However, since I am already in an IBAction of ANOTHER button (the button that created this view) I cannot initiate another IBAction.

Comment: So how can I perform a custom transition with these buttons while still making them appear programatically?